# How to disable App Extensions?

Tags: ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-app-extension, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

If I don't want the Pinterest app extension to show up in my UIActivityViewController, how can I remove it?  Previously I could just add the activity type to the excludedActivityTypes array.  That doesn't seem to work with app extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Applications require a special entitlement to exclude individual extension-provided activity items.  (Not 100% sure but) Managed devices can also have individual extensions blocked via MDM.